# KafkaTestUtils.getRecords() returns only first sent record

Tags: unit-testing, spring-kafka

Sending 4 records:

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", 0, "key1", "value1"));
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", 0, "key2", "value2"));
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", 0, "key3", "value3"));
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", 0, "key4", "value4"));
```

Using KafkaTestUtils.getRecords() get only first sent record;

```
final ConsumerRecords<String, OrderBookViewItem> records = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer, 10000);
```

Using consumer.poll() get all 4;

```
final Iterable<ConsumerRecord<String, OrderBookViewItem>> records = consumer.poll(1000).records("my-topic");
```

How to tune KafkaTestUtils to return all records or it is bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply returns whatever Kafka gives us on a `poll()` the method doesn't know how many records to fetch.

You can call it multiple times, or you can try setting the consumer properties `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` so that the `poll()` waits for more data.

See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) for more information about these properties.

Comment: Thanks! Config change helped.

Answer (score 1):

it works with 3 parameters (consumer, timeout, minRecords) for me:

```
final ConsumerRecords<String, OrderBookViewItem> records = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer, 10000, 4);
```

`minRecords` – wait until the timeout or at least this number of receords are